# Why is my Lambda API via Chalice giving an internal server error instead of a datetime value?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, rest, chalice

The API result at /date is giving an {"message": "Internal server error"} error. /hello is successfully returning 'hello  world'.

The ultimate goal is to return the number of days passed so far this year.

'''

```
from chalice import Chalice
from datetime import date

app = Chalice(app_name='days')
app.debug = True

@app.route('/hello')
def index():
    return {'hello': 'world'}

@app.route('/date')
def days():
    return date.today()
```

'''

Comment: Does `date.today()` return json?

Comment: Converting the output to a string, so it could be recognized by json, solved the issue. Thank you @Marcin!

Comment: Hi. Did it work when you added it as json?

Comment: Glad to hear. If you don't mind I will make an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was that `date.today()` was not **returning json**.

The solution was to **convert it to string** so that is correctly recognized as a json string: something like `str(date.today())`